# Web Api 2, with different kind of security

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web-api 2 project which uses tokens to recognize requester and then Authorize him using his roles.
I need to add another way for authentication for some methods. How to do it?

---

More data:
I have another system has to be able to call my service. It make more sense to me if it could work with a key and special IP.
With WCF, I usually defined 2 endpoints. 1 for users and 1 for my external systems. How is that possible in the web-api 2?